# Django: Template if statement executing even when false

Tags: python, django

I have the following in my template:

```
<li{% if selected == "al" %} id="selected" {% endif %}><a href="/posting/alerts">Alerts{% if alertnum != 0 %}<span style="color:red">({{alertnum}})</span>{% endif %}</a></li>
```

The problem is with the `alertnum != 0` it seems. I have the following view:

```
def posting_draft(request):
    user = request.user
    user_drafts = Draft.objects.filter(user = user)
    drafts = dict()
    for d in user_drafts:
        drafts[d.title] = d.id
    alertnum = get_alertnum(user) # Returns 0. I have used print statements to verify this
    return render_to_response('posting_draft.html', {'STATIC_URL':STATIC_URL, 'draft_l' : drafts, 'selected':"dr", alertnum: alertnum})
```

What shows up in browser when I load this, is `Alert ()` with empty red parenthesis. The parenthesis shouldn't be there at all since alertnum = 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if that's a typo, but you forgot the quotes around the alertnum in your context:

```
return render_to_response('posting_draft.html',
    {'STATIC_URL':STATIC_URL, 'draft_l' : drafts, 'selected':"dr", alertnum: alertnum})
```

So you are comparing `0 != 0`. It should be:

```
return render_to_response('posting_draft.html',
    {'STATIC_URL':STATIC_URL, 'draft_l' : drafts, 'selected':"dr", 'alertnum': alertnum})
```